# No module named 'samlib'

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning

I am trying to do "salience prediction". In my python code there is a module named "samlib", which I couldn't find anywhere. This is my code. Full code is in the Github reference is below (db.py).

```
import scipy.io
import numpy as np
import h5py
import os
import glob
***import samlib***
import utilities
import cv2
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold


        # start database
        self.db = h5py.File(self.dbname, 'w')

        names = glob.glob(self.path + 'images/*/*.jpg')

        im_dir = self.path + 'images/'
        fix_dir = self.path + 'fixation/'
        dense_dir = self.path + 'FIXATIONMAPS/'
        num = len(names)

        self.db['images'] = np.empty((num, 3, self.im_shape[0], self.im_shape[1]),
                                     dtype=np.float32)
        self.db['fixations'] = np.empty((num, self.gt_shape[0], self.gt_shape[1]),
                                    dtype=np.float32)
        self.db['maps'] = np.empty((num, self.gt_shape[0], self.gt_shape[1]),
                                    dtype=np.float32)
        self.db['class'] = np.empty(num, dtype=np.uint8) # the class of each box
        self.db['image_names'] = np.empty((num,1),dtype='|S150') # the image names

        ***pbar = samlib.misc.pba***r('Generate database:')
        for i, name in enumerate(pbar(names)):
            im, fix, dense = self.loadIm(name, im_dir, fix_dir, dense_dir)

            self.db['images'][i] = im
            self.db['fixations'][i] = fix
            self.db['maps'][i] = dense
```

**Reference : "https://github.com/sfdodge/mixsalnet"**

Comment: Edit in code :   pbar = samlib.misc.pbar(Generate database':)

Answer (score 0):

```
https://github.com/temikxd/samlib
```

Uploaded here for your reference.

Comment: Can you please explain the use of samlib module.

Comment: Its not written by me but used in a project as an external library. Add it to your project and you are good to go!